# Can't mount the screen to a docker container running on my laptop

Tags: docker

I have a Dell Vostro laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 OS connected to an external screen. I'm using a python 3.11 docker container running on my laptop to develop some application and I want to be able to create interactive plots. I know that one way of making interactive plots from a container running on the same host to which the screen is connected is to mount `/tmp/.X11-unix` to the container using `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` and setting the DISPLAY environment variable. I've done it many times before on different PCs. However, even though the container run successfully, when I list the content of `/tmp/.X11-unix` within the container I notice that it is empty (there are no screens listed) but the same folder on the host is non-empty. It seems like the mount didn't really work but no error is raised when running the container. Any ideas what could be wrong?

I tried docker run command with `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`. I also tried different base images. But it didn't work.

Comment: Your Ubuntu distribution comes with Python preinstalled, and I'd just use that directly without bothering with Docker.  If that's not an option for whatever reason, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]: what's the exact `docker run` command you're using, how have you set up things like the `.Xauthority` file, and what result are you getting?

Comment: Have you added access to xhost? Try command `xhost +` before container run.

Answer (score 0):

Key points to get access to display from docker is the following:

- set environment for container run `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY`, display number must be set beforehand like `export DISPLAY=:N`, display list can be seen in command output `xrandr --query`
- mount container volume `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`
- make sure you grant access to X for any local clients by running `xhost +` before container starts.